# new elementary OS user, wifi && graphics questions

Tags: wifi, drivers, hardware

I've done my homework and started using elementary OS on my Acer Swift 3

1. the **wifi** connectivity is terrible, windows gave me constant stable connection, where elementary OS fails to do that

   - Should i use *Ndiswrapper* with default intel drivers from my acer support site or **is there any other solution for faster and better connection**, current Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
2. the screen is "not so smooth" as before, should i try and use oibaf?

   - https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers
3. is TLP worth it?

---

My specs:

- Intel Core i5 8250u
- GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 62 | no dGPU (dedicated GPU)
- 8gb RAM

ref: https://ark.intel.com/products/124967/Intel-Core-i5-8250U-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3-40-GHz-

Comment: Are you still having these issues? If so, I suggest installing the HWE https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/02/how-to-install-ubuntu-18042-lts.html?m=1

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the other things you asked but TLP is worth it.
Just remember when you install TLP to go into terminal and type

```
sudo systemctl enable tlp

sudo systemctl start tlp
```